# Does creating a RAM disk in Linux really helpful in increasing performance?

Tags: linux

Does creating a RAM disk in Linux really helpful in increasing performance of a specific task or PC in general or there is no usage of free RAM in a Linux PC since the programs running are already loaded in the RAM there won't be any advantage to creating RAM disk.

Or there are other ways to use the free RAM available.

Comment: It all depends on what you need to do. The reality is in the modern age of SSD drives, RAM disks are kind of an archaic concept. The whole purpose of a RAM disk — in the past — was to compensate for the bottleneck of reading and writing to a physical hard drive. A task that could put extra strain on the disk and not even come close to being fast enough for many cases. So if you ask me, unless you have a specific need for a RAM disk — or you are on a hard disk based system — there is no real value in a RAM disk in the modern world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I am a seasoned Linux system administrator but I confess to not using RAM disks significantly under it).

In the general case a RAM disk will make things worse. (there are no doubt edge cases this is untrue). This is because of the way Linux uses RAM - it will use RAM as cache if there is any free. (If you do a `free`, it shows used RAM, free RAM and cache/buffers - you can add the cache and buffers back to get the actual free RAM as it will release it on request)

Simplifying a bit -

Linux will takes your excess RAM and uses it as a cache. While this won't help with writes (because a write could get lost) it can make a massive difference to reads, which are almost always cached if there us free memory, or stuff Linux thinks is less likely to be read)

In the general case Linux also more-or-less requires some swap. It uses this as a signal for memory management and having even a small amount will fix a lot of Out-Of-Memory issues. The problem is that (for reasons I still don't understand), Linux relies more then I believe it should on swap - which can slow things down. **If you are using a RAM disk for swap to fix this problem you are doing it wrong** Changing the VM.swappiness setting to a very low number (default is 60 - 10 or less is good) will heavily bias the memory management algorithm to use swap as a last resort and will greatly improve interactivity.

Programs do, of course run from RAM, and even if exited and rerun may launch from RAM because the programming has been cached.